# How do I extract text after <i class> tag?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, lxml

I am trying to print out the text 'Dealer' from div class by using beautifulSoup, but I do not know how to extract it.

I tried to print the i class, but the text Dealer did not come out

```py
url = 'https://www.carlist.my/used-cars-for-sale/proton/malaysia'
response = requests.get(url, params={'page_number': 1})
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')
articles = soup.find_all('article')[:25]
seller_type = articles[4].find('div', class_ = 'item push-quarter--ends listing__spec--dealer')
seller_type_text = articles[4].find('i', class_ = 'icon icon--secondary muted valign--top push-quarter--right icon--user-formal')

print(seller_type.prettify())
print()
print(seller_type_text)
```

This is the output that I got:

```py
<div class="item push-quarter--ends listing__spec--dealer">
 <i class="icon icon--secondary muted valign--top push-quarter--right icon--user-formal">
 </i>
 Dealer
 <span class="flyout listing__badge listing__badge--trusted-seller inline--block valign--top push-quarter--left">
  <i class="icon icon--thumb-up">
  </i>
  <span class="flyout__content flyout__content--tip visuallyhidden--portable">
   This 'Trusted Dealer' has a proven track record of upholding the best car selling practices certified by Carlist.my
  </span>
 </span>
 <!-- used car -->
 <!-- BMW -->
</div>


<i class="icon icon--secondary muted valign--top push-quarter--right icon--user-formal"></i>
```

How do I print the word 'Dealer' right after i class and before the span class?

Can someone please help me?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the contents property of your seller_type.  You'll see that Dealer is at seller_type.contents[2].  In other words,

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = 'https://www.carlist.my/used-cars-for-sale/proton/malaysia?profile_type=Dealer'
response = requests.get(url, params={'page_number': 1})
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')
articles = soup.find_all('article')[:25]
seller_type = articles[4].find('div', class_ = 'item push-quarter--ends listing__spec--dealer')
print(seller_type.contents[2])
```

Answer (score 3):

There is a faster way of using one of the compound class names of the `i` tag element along with `next_sibling`.

If you examine the html you can see "Dealer" is part of the parent `div` of the `i` tag, and follows the `i` tag; so, you can grab the `i` tag then use `next_sibling`

[image]

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests

r = requests.get('https://www.carlist.my/used-cars-for-sale/proton/malaysia')
soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
print(soup.select_one('.icon--user-formal').next_sibling)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = 'https://www.carlist.my/used-cars-for-sale/proton/malaysia?profile_type=Dealer'
response = requests.get(url, params={'page_number': 1})
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')
articles = soup.find_all('article')[:25]
seller_type = articles[4].find('div', class_ = 'item push-quarter--ends listing__spec--dealer')
print(seller_type.contents[2])
```